# Search Not Working for Second Library Web Part on Document Set Welcome Page

Tags: 2013, search, document-set

On my document set welcome page, I added a web part for a separate library and enabled the search bar. Search works fine for the document set's content, however, nothing is returning when I use the search bar for the second library. When I navigate to the second library itself, search works fine.

Is this expected behavior for document sets? When I have more than one library on a regular site page, I'm able to search both.

Comment: I hope second library has to be re-indexed. Did you check the files are searchable? Also check the search bar.

Comment: I tried re-indexing the library but that didn't work. The files are searchable through global search and when I use "find a file" on the library's default view page. The only place it doesn't work is on the document set welcome page. I even tried swapping it out with other libraries and they didn't work either.

Comment: I guess that document set has separate scope for results. What you can do is add content search web part and restrict the results of your cswp to that library.